# Bootstrap dropdown full-width with input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a dropdown zone to host a custom component. however, the dropdown is not from a standard dropdown but from an input group button.

I need this because I want a jstree down there as my selection need is too complex to fit in a simple select.

Here is what I would it to be like :

[image]

I would like for the dropdown zone to be the full width of the input. I've tried setting it at 100% but it seam to do nothing. A fixed with work but would break the responsivness of the site.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Options</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" style="width: 300px;">
                        <li>
                            aaaa<br />
                            aaaa<br />
                            aaaa<br />
                            aaaa<br />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Full jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rry7hr5b/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. 
**With Jquery.**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    function customwidth()
        {
            var formwidth = $('.form-group').width();       
            $('.dropdown-menu').width(formwidth);   
        }

        customwidth();
        $(window).resize(function(e) {
            customwidth();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Working well, thanks, there is just a typo, a double **w** in customwwidth.

Comment: Oh yes . Corrected.. and one thing you should remove min width on drop down ul..  

.dropdown-menu
{
    min-width:auto  (may be !important)
}

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround using the *.input-group-addon* instead of the *.input-group-btn*. It's neat, because you need no plugins or jQuery whatsoever. Mind however that the whole dropdown menu requires a minimum width.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon" style="padding:0; border:none; background:none">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" style="border-bottom-left-radius:0; border-top-left-radius:0">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:100%;">
        <li>aa</li>
        <li>aa</li>
        <li>aa</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rry7hr5b/5/

Comment: Nice! I used this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this kind of ul li for select item to customize Select in bootstrap there is plug-in available please try this

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

and here some more link..

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Comment: Thanks, but those don't match my need. The fact is that I need to include a jstree in it. If it was just for a select, I would have used a select2. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: please add screen shot for understand the requirement.

Comment: Not working at all, the dropdown content is still of fixed width when i need it to be 100% of the input-group width

Comment: here 100% in not working, bcz it's inside the small div input-group-btn, so get the dynamic width and assign that width via jquery to the ul https://jsfiddle.net/rry7hr5b/4/ refer here